# Bootstrap accordion click on header panel expand/collapse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this problem: My mobile application have some accordions based on the Bootstrap. The default behavior makes the collapse and expand works only on the inner link instead the full header panel. I need to change this, that way the accordion expands and collapse when the user click on any part of the header panel.

Answer (score 1):

I came with this solution. It is not very elegant, but works.

HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" onclick="javascript: expandAccordion( ' HospitalsAcc ' )">
    <a class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#TopStories" href="#HospitalsAcc">Hospitals</a>
</div>
<div id="HospitalsAcc" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
    <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: center">
        <p style="text-align: justify; margin: 0px">GeometryIndex: 1 </p>
        <p style="text-align: justify; margin: 0px">NAME: HOSPITAL </p>
        <p style="text-align: justify; margin: 0px">ADDRNO: 00 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    function expandAccordion(param) {
        param = param.trim();
        $('#'+param).collapse('toggle')
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a bit late to reply your answer but, it would be of help for future. 
If I understood your question correctly, you want a bootstrap accordion that expands and collapse on clicking the panel heading. Well here is the code:

```js
 function toggleIcon(e) {
        $(e.target)
            .prev('.panel-heading')
            .find(".more-less")
            .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    }
    $('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
    $('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
```

```css
 .panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
 }

 .panel-default > .panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
 }

 .panel-title {
  font-size: 14px;
 }

 .panel-title > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 .more-less {
  float: right;
  color: #212121;
 }

 .panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
 }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container demo">

 
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      Collapsible Group Item #1
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
       Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      Collapsible Group Item #2
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="panel-body">
     Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
      <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      Collapsible Group Item #3
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
    <div class="panel-body">
     Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div><!-- panel-group -->
 
 
</div><!-- container -->
```